# Finding the convergence/divergence of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

In the series:

$C_n = \dfrac{9^n}{n!}$

How do you figure out whether it converges or diverges?

I've tried writing it out a little bit, but it doesn't really help much . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

We know $$e^x=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\frac{x^r}{r!}$$

or we can use $$\lim_{r\to\infty}\frac{C_{r+1}}{C_r}=\lim_{r\to\infty}\frac9{r+1}=0$$

Comment: Why does the lim (Cr+1)/(Cr) approaching 0 prove that the series itself approaches 0?

Comment: Your question was, divergence or convergence? Convergence does not mean that the series approaches zero. Maybe you should first look up the definitions in your textbook, elsewhere the answers here will not help, since you do  not understand them.

Comment: @user3776574, Converges means the sum tends to a finite constant value

Comment: I understand that, but then, why does it prove divergence at all?

Comment: Please consult your textbook first!! @lab means that this proves **convergence**. Apparently you don't grasp the meaning of convergence and therefore also not what lab wants to say.

Answer (score 0):

Since $e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{x^n}{n!}$, clearly, the series is equal to $e^9$.